# How to know number of lines/rows in FlexboxLayout android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using FlexBoxLayout in android and want to know the number of rows or lines occupied.
I have added multiple textviews in this flex layout dynamically.

Have tried this solution

```
binding.flexLayout.flexLines.size
```

but it return the number of items in flex layout.

I'm using configuration in my flexbox layout

```
app:flexWrap="wrap"
app:justifyContent="flex_start"
```

Please suggest a valid solution.
Thanks